# Gierer-Meinhardt equation

Tags: geometry, partial-differential-equations

i am new here.

can anyone help me & give advice on how to tackle Gierer-Meinhardt equation? it is among the reaction diffusion equation.

is there any links that can help me?

i am asking on how to answer them mathematically not by software of that sort. just need to know how to derived them.

[the equation](https://i.stack.imgur.com/geN0v.png)

Answer (score 0):

Actually, the proof of the equation requires identification of the purported morphogens, measurement of their spatiotemporal concentrations and kinetics, and demonstration by knockouts or other genetic manipulations that they are essential components of the observed pattern formation. But, I hope this [link](http://core.ac.uk/download/pdf/336496.pdf) will help you.

Comment: right now, i am having problem to derived the equation from turing.. is there any research that actually shows the full calculation & step to solve it? i really lost here..